# Как правильно: свойство float в css или Flexbox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как в настоящее время правильно верстать с помощью 
свойства `float` в CSS или использовать FlexBox, если нужно расположить блоки горизонтально.

Comment: flex - https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex

Comment: Понятие "правильно" - весьма относительно. Отталкивайтесь от требований к поддержке IE, если он для вас не принципиален - не вижу причин использовать float.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду изучать FlexBox.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знала как лучше задать вопрос, чтобы было кратко и понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для расположения блоков, сетки, учи css grid, с помощью его можно делать очень легко и быстро расположение элементов, чем то похож на flexbox, но у них разные предназначения, flexbox нужен для создания какай-нибудь  навигации, css grid для макета. От float уже можно отказываться, сейчас с появлением css grid и flexbox они не нужны.

Answer (score 4):

Используй flexBox с ним гораздо меньше проблем. Он удобнее float и более функционален.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста, если мне нужно горизонтально расположить два блока, а третий должен располагаться внизу. Насколько я знаю, можно так сделать с помощью FlexBox, если ширину блока указано в px. А если ширина в%, то они сужаются, но внизу не располагаются. А надо внизу.

Comment: Есть такое свойство у FlexBox? Я еще новичок и много не знаю. Буду благодарна за ответ.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Или если просто хотите расположить блоки  в линию, то используйте display: inline-block; Полностью поддерживаю человека внизу. Но если вам надо Более сложное расположение, то конечно flexbox.

Comment: Нужно при определенном размере экрана, чтобы два блока были горизонтально, а третий располагался под ними. При большом размере экрана все три блока располагаются горизонтально. Я знаю как это делать, используя float. А можно так с помощью FlexBox? Я немного его знаю, но с блоками не получается. 
А какие именно свойства FlexBox нужно использовать?

Comment: Спасибо. 
Подскажите с помощью каких свойств FlexBox можно сделать то, что я спрашивала выше.

Comment: Вы можете использовать медиа запросы для адаптивности. Если можете, вставьте код заготовки

Comment: это понятно. Вопрос в том, что размер экрана малый и надо расположить два блока рядом, а третий под ними, потому что три горизонтально на мобильных устройствах некрасиво выглядят визуально и трудно читать. и как это можно сделать с помощью FlexBox?

Comment: <div class="main2">
<div class="little_tel1"><img src="img/little_tel1.gif" alt="" />
<h2>new product</h2>
<p>Ella is a brand new , native mobile<br /> app for parents with children</p></div>
<div class="little_tel2"><img src="img/little_tel2.gif" alt=""/>
<h2>unique features</h2>
<p>Meet other families and your<br /> children are looking for friends to live<br /> together!</p></div>
<div class="little_tel3"><img src="img/little_tel3.gif" alt=""/>
<h2>ease of use</h2>
<p>Free and easy to use product</p></div>
</div><!--end main2-->

Comment: это часть кода. там есть три блока с текстом и картинками. мне нужно, чтобы при определенном размере экрана блоки little_tel1 и little_tel2 располагались горизонтально, а блок little_tel3 - под ними. но с помощью свойств FlexBox. Извините, если непонятно спрашиваю.

Comment: Вы можете использовать медиа запросы для адаптивности.